# Typo3 : Get URL Segment ( SLUG) field in sys_category table

Tags: typo3

I have a TYPO3 project ( v9.5) and I didn't have the URL segment field to create a slug for my categories ( table sys_category) while on other projects I have this field.

[image]

This field isn't created by default ?

Is it possible to get this field?

Answer (score 0):

This field "sys_category.slug" is shipped with the news extension:

https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/news

Comment: I already have news system extension, but in version 7.0.8, the slug field was added in a specific version ?